# Azure Service Bus Partitioning and Order

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a question around Azure Service Bus partitioning that I can’t find in the documentation.

Here is the scenario:

We have a ton of service request messages that come through our system.  They are for a specific person.  We have so many that we need to have many instances of our message processing service pulling down the messages and processing them.  The order in which we process the messages does not really matter, with the exception that the messages for single person need to be processed in order.  For example, if we got a message requesting service for person 123, then another message modifying the request for service for person 123, we need to process those in the order we got them.

Reading through the partitioning, it seems like we could pass in the person's ID as the partitioning key.  This would ensure that the messages are correctly ordered on each partitioned broker.  However, I am concerned about the processing of the messages.

I want to think that if we set the queue to be partitioned, then only 1 message can be in process  from each partition at a time.  But I can’t seem to find any documentation that confirms this.  If that is the case, then that would ensure that we don’t have messages for a single person passing each other up in the queue.

**Does Azure Service Bus enforces a “1 un-settled message per partition” limit?**

Note: I read about Sessions, but they seem to work only when you have a pre-known and finite set of groups.  The list of Person IDs I would have is vast, and trying to setup a session receiver for each of them would quickly get out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions do not seem to be what you're looking for.  When you create a partitioned entity, Service Bus stores each partition in a separate store and each is handled by a different broker.  When reading, there is no guarantee for ordering - Service Bus queries all partitions for messages and returns a message from whichever partition responds first.  A more detailed discussion can be found in [Partitioned queues and topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#how-it-works).

Sessions, on the other hand, sound like what you're looking for.  Each session has a lock associated and can be read by only one active reader.  I'm not sure why you believe that you need to know the number of sessions ahead of time, but there's no [quota](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas) limitation that I'm aware of that restricts the number of sessions.

For processing, you would be able to use a single [ServiceBusSessionProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussessionprocessor?view=azure-dotnet) if you wanted and cycle through all sessions - or as many as you'd like so that you can process sessions concurrently.

If you'd prefer to control things more explicitly, using the [AcceptNextSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient.acceptnextsessionasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusclient-acceptnextsessionasync(system-string-azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebussessionreceiveroptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method on `ServiceBusClient` would let you spawn an ephemeral receiver associated with a specific session that you would read from and close when you're done with that session.